# Update Shiny Plots based on input from slider

Tags: shiny, slider, reactive

I have made four Plots in four boxes on a Shiny Dashboard Page. I wish to represent all the four plots dynamically in one box based on an input from Slider ranging from 1 to 4. All the plots are different and are not related. I wish to know the basic Syntax to do that. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

As @Pork Chop commented you should check out [the website which is going to help you in asking the question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

As you are new in this community i am going give you a hint how to update shiny plots with input from slider.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

data <-  data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(10,11,12,13))
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sliderInput("slider","Slider", min=1, max=4, step =1, value=1)),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(column(6,plotOutput('plot1'),plotOutput('plot2')),
             column(6,plotOutput('plot3'),plotOutput('plot4'))
                         )))
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data,aes_string(x=input$slider, y="y"))+geom_point(size=5)
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data,aes_string(y=input$slider, x="y"))+geom_point(size=5)
  })

  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data,aes_string(y=input$slider, x="y"))+geom_line(size=5)
  })

  output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data,aes_string(x=input$slider, y="y"))+geom_line(size=5)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Next time do not forget to create some sample code and sample data!**

Comment: Hi Mal_a, Firstly thank you so much for your effort, I have one more query and I hope you can resolve it. Would really appreciate. Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483350/dynamic-hover-to-represent-data-population-in-r-tool